# I am getting "null pointer Exception" with com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method. when used PageFactory in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit, nullpointerexception

I am getting "null pointer Exception" with com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method. when used PageFactory in selenium.

I am trying to create a Test case using Junit . When i try to invoke the methods which is present in the parent class I am facing Null pointer exception

My code as follows

```
class 1:

public class Browser {

public static RemoteWebDriver driver;

public void openInternetExplorer(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path to ie driver");
      driver = new InterExplorerDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.gmail.com")
    }
}

Class2:

public class Elements extends Browser{

public enterText(WebElement element, String text){

element.sendKeys(text);
}
}

Class3:

public BaseClass extends Elements{

BaseClass(){
PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

}

Class4:

public Testing extends BaseClass{

@FindBy(id="unique_name") WebElement uniqName;


public void method1(){
openInternetExplorer();
enterText(uniqName,"SuperMan");

}

}


Error Which i am getting is

    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at        org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(Defaul  tElementLocator.java:69)
    at      org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(L     ocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.framework.Browser.clickAction(Element.java:5)
    at com.framework.Testing.Testing(Testing.java:7)
```

Please let me know if I miss something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute `PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);` 
in the Testing class before calling `enterText(uniqName,"SuperMan");` method to invoke the elements.

Otherwise your @FindBy elements won't be invoked.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have already added PageFactory.initElements(driver,this); in BaseClass Constructor and extended. I guess the constructor would be invoked first and then it will proceed with the execution if @FindBy()

Comment: Yes but that will only invoke elements defined in BaseClass that won't be applicable for Testing class WebElements

Comment: Thank you kushal. It worked when i added  PageFactory.initElements(driver,this); excatly before the enterText()                       some thing like this    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this); enterText(); Then it worked.